# jQuery, Anchor, ScrollTo, highlight

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, anchor

I have a large threaded comment list. When a person replies the author gets an email notification.

I'd like the email to have a link to the reply something like: http://site.com/feedback/#reply-22

the page would have something like wow nice comment

With jQuery how can I detect the anchor, slowly scroll to the location on page load, and then once it's scrolled to the location highlight the DIV, not highlighting until the scroll is completed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), which might be useful for you. It's a jQuery plugin that allows you to slowly scroll to locations based on just about anything you need.

[Here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) is the link to the project download page.

Use the `onAfter:function() {}` ability to highlight the comment once the scroll is completed.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is simple (thanks to its use of .animate and .effect) and works well: [jSlideto](https://github.com/djpate/jSlideto/).